# deconvolve 2D array

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

There is an 2D array representing an image `a` and a kernel representing a pointspread function `k`. `scipy.signal.deconvolve` returns "objects too deep for desired array", from the internally called `lfilter` function. 1D arrays are working flawlessly. How can this be fixed?

```
import numpy as N
import scipy.signal as SS
# working
# taken from:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063775/convolution-and-deconvolution-in-python-using-scipy-signal
a = N.array([  0.5,   2.5,   6. ,   9.5,  11. ,  10. ,   9.5,  11.5,  10.5,
5.5,   2.5,   1. ])
k= N.array([0.5, 1.0, 0.5])
res1,res2 = SS.deconvolve(a, k)
# not working
a = N.ones((10,10))
k = N.array([[1,2],[2,1]])
res1, res2 = SS.deconvolve(a,k)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that would be because `scipy.signal.deconvolve()` only supports 1D deconvolution! Unfortunately the docs aren't clear on this fact.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473917/is-there-a-equivalent-of-scipy-signal-deconvolve-for-2d-arrays) for frequency-domain 2D deconvolution.

Comment: Thanks, I did indeed not realize that. I will play around with the code from the other thread.